# How to remove a JointGrid margin frame

Tags: python, seaborn, jointplot, jointgrid

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sample data
penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins')

g = sns.JointGrid(data=penguins, x='bill_length_mm', y='bill_depth_mm', space=0) 

g.plot_joint(sns.scatterplot)
sns.despine(top=False)
g.plot_marginals(sns.histplot, kde=True, bins=250, color='r')
g.ax_marg_x.remove()
```

In this code, I am trying to plot a figure and marginal distribution of an axis. However, I could not do something. How can I remove the right and left margin borders in this figure?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`set_frame_on(False)` works with `g.ax_marg_y`, and `g.ax_marg_x`, to remove the y margin frame, and x margin frame, respectively.

```py
g = sns.JointGrid(data=penguins, x='bill_length_mm', y='bill_depth_mm', space=0) 

g.plot_joint(sns.scatterplot)
sns.despine(top=False, right=False)
g.plot_marginals(sns.histplot, kde=True, bins=250, color='r')
g.ax_marg_x.remove()

g.ax_marg_y.set_frame_on(False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Instead of using `g.plot_marginals`, which plots the function in both margins, and then requires several lines of code to reformat, only plot in the specific margin, `ax=g.ax_marg_y`.

```py
g = sns.JointGrid(data=penguins, x="bill_length_mm", y="bill_depth_mm", space=0) 

g.plot_joint(sns.scatterplot)

sns.histplot(data=penguins, y="bill_depth_mm", kde=True, bins=250, color='r', ax=g.ax_marg_y)
```

[image]

- The other option is to use `sns.jointplot`

```py
g = sns.jointplot(data=penguins, x='bill_length_mm', y='bill_depth_mm', space=0,
                  marginal_kws=dict(bins=250, fill=False, kde=True, color='r'))

# remove the x-margin plot, which includes the spine for the margin
g.ax_marg_x.remove()

# makes the joint spine visible
g.ax_joint.spines[['top']].set_visible(True)
```